# How to write a function that can be available in all Razor views?

Tags: razor

I'm trying to write a function that can bring a language resource from database in MVC 5 and Razor,
I want it to be very simple to use, for example, the following function should just get some text:

```
@T("ResourceType", "ResourceName")
```

I don't want to use @this. - just the the function name...

I saw some posts about it mentioning the line below, but still trying to understand how to do it

```
public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it, inspired by the NopCommerce project, see the code below.

The code can be used in any Razor (cshtml) view like this:

```
<h1>@T("StringNameToGet")</h1>
```

Also, note that pageBaseType needs to be updated with the correct new namespace,
this is the web.config in the Views folder - not the main one, should look like this:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="MyNameSpace.Web.Extensions.WebViewPage">
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="APE.Web" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

The code:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Web.Extensions
{
public delegate LocalizedString Localizer(string text, params object[] args);

public abstract class WebViewPage : WebViewPage<dynamic>
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Update the pages element /views/web.config to reflect the 
/// pageBaseType="MyNameSpace.Web.Extensions.WebViewPage"
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    private Localizer _localizer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a localized resources
    /// </summary>
    public Localizer T
    {
        get
        {
            if (_localizer == null)
            {
                //null localizer
                //_localizer = (format, args) => new LocalizedString((args == null || args.Length == 0) ? format : string.Format(format, args));

                //default localizer
                _localizer = (format, args) =>
                {
                    var resFormat = SampleGetResource(format);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resFormat))
                    {
                        return new LocalizedString(format);
                    }
                    return
                        new LocalizedString((args == null || args.Length == 0)
                            ? resFormat
                            : string.Format(resFormat, args));
                };
            }
            return _localizer;
        }
    }

    public string SampleGetResource(string resourceKey)
    {
        const string resourceValue = "Get resource value based on resourceKey";

        return resourceValue;
    }
}

public class LocalizedString : System.MarshalByRefObject, System.Web.IHtmlString
{
    private readonly string _localized;
    private readonly string _scope;
    private readonly string _textHint;
    private readonly object[] _args;

    public LocalizedString(string localized)
    {
        _localized = localized;
    }

    public LocalizedString(string localized, string scope, string textHint, object[] args)
    {
        _localized = localized;
        _scope = scope;
        _textHint = textHint;
        _args = args;
    }

    public static LocalizedString TextOrDefault(string text, LocalizedString defaultValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return defaultValue;

        return new LocalizedString(text);
    }

    public string Scope
    {
        get { return _scope; }
    }

    public string TextHint
    {
        get { return _textHint; }
    }

    public object[] Args
    {
        get { return _args; }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _localized; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _localized;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return _localized;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashCode = 0;
        if (_localized != null)
            hashCode ^= _localized.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != GetType())
            return false;

        var that = (LocalizedString)obj;
        return string.Equals(_localized, that._localized);
    }
}
```

}